# Synchronizing four shell scripts to run one after another in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, informatica

I have 4 shell script to generate a file(let's say param.txt) which is used by another tool(informatica) and as the tool is done with processing, it deletes param.txt.

The intent here is all four scripts can get invoked at different time lets say 12:10 am, 12:13 am, 12:16 am, 12:17 am. First script runs at 12:10am and creates param.txt and trigger informatica process which uses param.txt. Informatica process takes another 5-10 minutes to complete and deletes the param.txt. The 2nd script invokes at 12:13 am and waits for unavailability of param.txt and as informatica process deletes it, script 2 creates new param.txt and triggers same informatica again. The same happen for another 2 scripts.

I am using Until and sleep commands in all 4 shell script to check the unavailability of param.txt like below:

```
until [ ! -f "$paramfile" ]
do
    Sleep 10
done
<create param.txt file>
```

Issue here is, sometimes when all 4 scripts begin, the first one succeeds and generates param.txt(as there was no param.txt before) and other waits but when informatica process completes and deletes param.txt, remaining 3 scripts or 2 of them checks the unavailability at same time and one of them creates it but all succeed. I have checked different combinations of sleep interval between four scripts but this situation is occurring almost every time.

Comment: look into creating a temp txt file in `/var/tmp` at the begining of each script and deleting it when it ends

Comment: Is there anything preventing the informatica processes from running concurrently other than the fact that they all appear to be hard-coded to look for `params.txt`?

Comment: No, param.txt changes after each script run and informatica workflow shall pickup the changed param.txtx in each run.

Comment: You would still benefit from making the input file name a parameter; each process would simply wait for its specific input to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing a classical race condition. To solve this issue, you need a shared "lock" (or similar) between your 4 scripts.

There are several ways to implement this. One way to do this in bash is by using the `flock` command, and an agreed-upon filename to use as a lock. The [flock man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) has some usage examples which resemble this:

```
(
    flock -x 200  # try to acquire an exclusive lock on the file
    # do whatever check you want. You are guaranteed to be the only one
    # holding the lock
    if [ -f "$paramfile" ]; then
        # do something
    fi
) 200>/tmp/lock-life-for-all-scripts
# The lock is automatically released when the above block is exited
```

You can also ask `flock` to fail right away if the lock can't be acquired, or to fail after a timeout (e.g. to print "still trying to acquire the lock" and restart).

Depending on your use case, you could also put the lock on the 'informatica' binary (be sure to use `200<` in that case, to open the file for reading instead of (over)writing)

Comment: depending on what `<create param.txt file>` actually is, you may be able to have it call `open()` with the `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` flags set. The `open()` call will either succeed and create the file if it does not yet exist; or it will fail if the file does exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Niobos. I used your answer to modify my script like this. (
    flock -x -n 800
 until [ ! -f "$paramfiletmp" ]
 do
  Sleep 10
 done
  $paramFile > $paramfiletmp #(this step creates param.tx)
) 800>/var/tmp/lockforScripts. I am not good at scripting and can't figure out the issue here. Error I am getting is - '800' unexpected. Btw I am using Solaris.

Comment: The script is very hard to read in your comment. Based on the error you are getting, you should double-check if there is no space between the `800` and the `>`.

Comment: What the 2nd `200` does?

Comment: the `flock` line acquires a lock on file descriptor number 200. The `200>` part opens the file `/tmp/lock`... for writing (`>`) on file descriptor number 200. It's similar to using `2>error-output.log` for file descriptor number 2 (standard error output). The choice of number 200 is arbitrary. You can pick whataver, it just needs to be free for use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GNU Parallel** as a counting semaphore or a mutex, by invoking it as `sem` instead of as `parallel`. Scroll down to `Mutex` on [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Semaphore).

So, you could use:

```
sem --id myGlobalId 'create input file; run informatica'
sem --id myGlobalId 'create input file; run informatica'
sem --id myGlobalId 'create input file; run informatica'
sem --id myGlobalId 'create input file; run informatica'
```

Note I have specified a global `id` in case you run the jobs from different terminals or cron. This is not necessary if you are starting all jobs from one terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your valuable suggestions. It did help me to think from other dimension. However I missed to mention that I am using Solaris UNIX where I couldn't find equivalent of flock or similar function. I could have asked team to install one utility but in mean time I found a workaround for this issue.

I read about the mkdir function being atomic in nature where as 'touch' command to create a file is not(still don't have complete explanation on how it works). That means at a time only 1 script can create/delete directory 'lockdir' out of 4 and other 3 has to wait.

```
while true;
do 
if mkdir "$lockdir"; then
   < create param file >

break;
fi
    Sleep 30
done
```