# Limiting the number of simultaneous instances of a program executed within a Perl script (to >1)

Tags: perl

I'm using a resource-intensive program in a Perl script [specifically `rclone` to transfer files to Google Drive].

I have yet to figure out how I want to call `rclone`, as I need to limit the number of instances of `rclone` based on some condition (*anything* relevant to preventing server overload, freezing, crashing, etc.). I would like for the script to wait for the apt system "conditions" (this can be for some long or indefinite amount of time) before it executes `rclone`.

Some details:

- The script itself is essentially passed a file or directory path containing (possibly numerous) files by another program (this program written in Python--call this program `<A>` for reference).
- `<A>` only returns a value to a script and thus knows nothing about the script or `rclone`, other than that it accepts input.
- `<A>` cannot be altered (i.e. changing `<A>` is  beyond my ken)
- `<A>` fires at varying intervals [i.e. sometimes it will execute the script many times rapidly in succession (creating multiple instances), other times it might only fire once every few hours, minutes, etc.]
- Assume that `rclone` can't be altered directly either (i.e. again, beyond my ken).
- If absolutely necessary, the number of instances of the script can be limited instead of `rclone` (though I'd prefer it only be `rclone`, as the processing done by the script is rather light and needs no limitation).
- Modules are fine to use.
- I would like to avoid using Unix-like operating system commands like `pgrep` and `ps` (unless absolutely necessary).

Currently, I'm using a rather poorly written bash script in place of the Perl script. The bash script implements a rudimentary (poorly designed) "check/sleep loop" using `pgrep -wc`, `sleep`, `while` loops and `if` statements. (To be honest, I don't even think the bash script really works/helps atm.)

Comment: You can invoke **GNU Parallel** as `sem -j N` and it will only allow `N` instances to run in parallel https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206137/2836621 and https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html

Comment: @Mark Ah yes, totally forgot about that useful program, and it's written in Perl too. Do you know if the semaphore functionality works if the command is called multiple times, with each time in a _different_ script? That is---using the toilet analogy----does each script instance have its own "room of toilets" which no other script instances can access, or do all script instances use the same "room"?

Comment: Yes, as long as the different programs all give the same `--id` like in the answer I linked.

Comment: If server freezing is an issue, you can use `--timeout` to kill `rclone` if it takes much longer than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume for a moment that your script is the only thing running `rclone`. If you wanted only 1 copy running, [you would just use a lockfile](http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/tech/flock.html).

For N instances (for small N), I would just have N lockfiles - have the program try each lock in turn, in a loop; pause if all the locks are already held and retry 1s later, in a loop. Once it has a lock, run `rclone` then release the lock when it is done.

---

A more sound approach would be to use SysV semaphores but, unless you want a large N, really care about response times or are worried about fairness between callers, it is not likely to be worth the time learning them.

---

If your script is not the only program calling `rclone`, then would need to intercept all calls - instead of putting this code in your program, could replace `rclone` by wrapper that implements the parallelism constraint as above and then calls the real program.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel can work on a job queue https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

```
true >jobqueue; tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel -j10 --timeout 1h rclone
```

And then run `<A>` as this:

```
<A> >> jobqueue
```

You will now and then have to clean up `jobqueue`. But unless `<A>` produces an insane amount of data, then it will typically be enough simply to zero it (`true >jobqueue`) at every reboot.