# Atomic read and truncate of file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, atomic

I am creating a process scheduler and all processes are started like `./program > out.txt`.

While the program is running & the output is produced, how can I read all the data and truncate the file atomicaly, i.e. guarantee that no data will be written after the read operation before the file is truncated.

- I can not modify the schedule command or the program. The data collector however knows the data producer process PID and the data collector is allowed to control/pause the process.
- By all "read all the data" I mean all flushed data. If I can force externally to flush the pipe, it will be helpful and please write, but the primary question is how to make sure that unflushed/buffered pipe data will never be flushed between the read & truncate operation.

Comment: You can use **GNU Parallel** as a semaphore https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206137/2836621

Comment: `pause the data producer` - but the data to write are inside the process. `printf` has a 4K size internal buffer - process internal buffer. So each time you do `printf("blabla")` it just `strcpy(&somebuf[pos], "blabla"); pos+=strlen("blabla");`. The buffer is internal to the process. I don't get what you exactly want. You can `stdbuf -o0 ./program`. The `>` is a redirection, the `|` is a pipe.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, I have updated the question. Basically the data are produced and the data collector reads the data file and truncates it time by time. When I will pause the process, is it guaranteed that the data file is immediatelly up-to-date, i.e. no race condition / additional bytes will be written during the read & truncate operation?

Comment: Yes. And no. Depends how deep you want to go. On filesystem/kernel level the data can be in buffers. But for the shell (or any process), it acts as-if the data are written. So, you basically want to read `out.txt` data without loosing any output from your process? So pause the process, `cp out.txt out.txt.to_read` + `truncate out.txt` + unpause the process. And then read `out.txt.to_read`.

Comment: Normally you can put a wrapper around a command. So if your simulation does `schedule A`, you can rename `schedule` as `schedule.orig` and write a new schedule script that does something else first then `exec`s `schedule.orig`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, but I then the process management (like signalling) is much more complicated and more processes will be running (I need it for Uni / mass scale) so I want to avoid wrapping the command as much as possible.

Comment: When I will pause the data producer process (and wait before the process is marked as paused), does the linux spec guarantee that the pipe buffer will be never flushed, ie. it will be frozen (or flushed before the process is marked as paused)?

Answer (score 2):

You can pause and continue a process with

```
kill -STOP $pid
kill -CONTINUE $pid
```

However, I don't think `kill -STOP $pid` is synchronous, so you should then loop and wait until the process changes state (available in `/proc` or via `ps`).

Also, because of PID recycling, the above operations will be inherently racy (you can hit an unintended process) unless you make them from the parent of `$pid` in such a way that the pid isn't reaped until you're done with the `kill` calls (interactive shells reap pids automatically in a SIGCHLD handler).

Comment: When I will pause the data producer process (and wait before the process is marked as paused), does the linux spec guarantee that the pipe buffer will be never flushed, ie. it will be frozen (or flushed before the process is marked as paused)?

Comment: As for the PID I know about the recycling when the process is terminated/finished, but when I pause/stop the process, the PID is never changed, or is it?

Comment: @Mvorisek If you "know" a pid but aren't its parent, all you have is a volatile reference. Killing by that pid is shooting at a moving target. The process could have died, its parent could have reaped it, and then if the kill succeeded, you've killed a processes you didn't intend to kill. Only if you're the parent can you guarantee you haven't reaped (==`wait`ed on it) the child and so its pid couldn't have been recycled.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I save & compare the start time of that PID.

Comment: Do you know if linux guarantee once the process is (synchronous, i.e. shown as) stopped that the pipe buffer will be never flushed, ie. it will stay frozen or be flushed before the process is marked as stopped. Do you know if it is guaranteed or if this behaviour can be somehow enforced after the process is paused/stopped (without disabling the pipe buffers)?

Comment: @Mvorisek From what you've shown, you don't have a pipe in this. Only a redirection.  I believe if you can order a `write()` in one process with a `stat`/`fstat` in another it should always reflect the result of the last write. OSs should always give you a uniform view of the file system regardless of any synchronicity that happens under the hood (disk writes are typically delayed). I don't know of an official guarantee, but if you can show that an OS expands a file by itself when all writers to it are stopped, you have found a kernel bug.

Answer (score -1):

You might try [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

From the man page:

```
(
flock -s 200

# ... commands executed under lock ...

) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

Comment: Thank you, I can not modify the schedule command. I have updated the question as it seems that it is primary about if linux guarantee that the pipe buffer will be never flushed, ie. it will stay frozen or be flushed before the process is marked as paused. Do you know if it is guaranteed or if this behaviour can be somehow enforced after the process is paused/stopped (without disabling the pipe buffers)?